# Colour report rows that contain the same product name

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a list of products and I am trying to alternate the colour between each product (grey, white, grey, white, and so on). I understand how to use colour formatting based on a condition such as the following link: [example followed](http://dbswh.webhop.net/htmldb/f?p=BLOG%3aREAD:0%3a%3a%3a%3aARTICLE:351800346145832). However I dont know how to get it to look at the previous line on the report and check whether it holds the same product name. If it does, then colour the row the same colour, else the alternate colour.
I've setup an example report in the application: Application 67666 - Colour Row by Product example. I have two products in the report so I'm trying to get 3 grey lines and then 3 white lines, if I had more products it would then go back to grey and so on.

Link:apex.oracle.com

workspace: apps2

user: user

password: DynamicAction2

Please could I be directed in the right direction, JavaScript and Dynamic Actions shout out to me as in the example link however its looking at the previous row which is getting me all stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of another solution than javascript really. There is possibly using [lag in the sql](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/lag.php), but only to use it to determine where the row color should change. You could use the value of the column in a html expression of a column and put it in a class, but you still need to iterate over it with javascript anyway. So it seems less fiddly to just use javascript.

Inline CSS:

```
table.report-standard tr.normalRow td{
background-color: green;
}
table.report-standard tr.altRow td{
background-color: red;
}
```

This will override the default style, but you will need to tune this to your demands. For example, the color change on :hover of the row. I prefer steering the style through assigning classes and then define the rules in css than to directly assign css through javascript (which would place it in style tags, ugh).

- Dynamic action: change row colour
- After Refresh, Region, Product Report
- True action: execute javascript code, fire on page load checked

  ```
  $('td[headers="PRODUCT"]', this.triggeringElement).each(function(){
  var lCurrRow = $(this).closest('tr'),
      lPrevRow = lCurrRow.prev(), 
      lPrevVal = lPrevRow.find('td[headers="PRODUCT"]').text();
  console.log(lPrevVal + ' - ' + $(this).text());
  //if value on previous row differs from the that on the current row
  //then change the class
  //if the value didnt change, then use the same class as the previous row
  if ( lPrevVal != $(this).text() ){
    if ( lPrevRow.hasClass('normalRow') ){
      lCurrRow.addClass('altRow');
    } else {
      lCurrRow.addClass('normalRow');
    };
  } else {
    if ( lPrevRow.hasClass('normalRow') ){
      lCurrRow.addClass('normalRow');
    } else {
      lCurrRow.addClass('altRow');
    };
  };
  })
  ```

Check your solution on apex.oracle.com, I implemented it there.